# Integral Existence

Tags: integration, measure-theory, functional-calculus

If we know that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\frac{d|\mu|(t)}{t+1}<\infty,$$ how can I prove that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\frac{z}{1+tz}d\mu(t)<\infty$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\mu$ is a complex Radon Measure? In this case, $|\mu|$ stands for the total variation of measure $\mu$.

I had the follow hint: $$\frac{1}{1+tz}-\frac{1}{1+t}=\frac{t(1-z)}{1+tz}\frac{1}{1+t}.$$

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Consider $z = -1$ and $d\mu = - \chi_{(0,2)}(x) \, dx$, where $\chi_M$ is the characteristic function/indicator function of the set $M$.

We then have $d |\mu| = \chi_{(0,2)}(x) \, dx$ and hence

$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}_+} \frac{1}{1+t} \, d|\mu|(t) = \int_0^2 \frac{1}{1+t} \, dt< \infty,
$$

but

$$
\int_{\Bbb{R}_+} \frac{z}{1+tz} \, d\mu(t) = \int_0^2 \frac{1}{1-t} \, dt = \infty,
$$
because the singularity at $t = 1$ is not integrable w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I forgot that $|\mu|$ stands for the total variation of measure $\mu$. Does this change anything?

Comment: @Marcelo_B: I already interpreted $|\mu|$ as the total variation. Hence, this does not change anything.

Comment: Look this my friend's solution:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}
\left|\frac{z}{1+zt}d\mu(t)\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}
\dfrac{|z|}{|1+tz|}d|\mu|(t)$ 

$= |z|\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}
\left|\frac{1}{1+tz}\right|d|\mu|(t) =|z|
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\left|\left(\frac{t(1-z)}{1+tz}+1\right)\frac{1}{1+t}\right|d|\mu|(t)$


 $\leq |z|\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} M(z) \frac{1}{1+t}d|\mu|(t)
\leq |z|M(z)\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}\frac{d|\mu|(t)}{t+1}<\infty.$

I think he is correct, but I'd like understand your conterexample. Does your measure a Radon measure?

Thank you so much for help me.

Comment: @Marcelo_B: Yes, my measure is a finite Radon measure. In your solution, what is $M(z)$?